# Delphi - DBGrid não substitui conteúdo da primeira linha

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Bom dia pessoal...

Tenho uma tabela em um banco SQLite com um campo do tipo "inteiro" para guardar valores "boolean". Este campo está ligado, na tela de cadastro, a um DBCheckbox. Então, para conseguir marcar e desmarcar o DBCheckbox, eu precisei escrever os eventos OnGetText e OnSetText do campo.

Agora estou necessitando mostrar valores "Sim" e "Não" baseados nesse campo em um DBGrid. Escrevi o código abaixo no evento OnDrawColumnCell:

```
procedure TfrmPesquisar.dbgPesquisarDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
   if Column.Field = dsPesquisar.DataSet.FieldByName('claAtiva') then
  begin
    dbgPesquisar.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    if Column.Field.AsString = '0' then
      dbgPesquisar.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+10,Rect.Top+3,'Não')
    else
      dbgPesquisar.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+10,Rect.Top+3,'Sim');
  end;
end;
```

Porém, somente a primeira linha está apresentando, erradamente, o valor a ser substituído (Não) e o valor real (0 - zero), conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante ou conhece a solução ?

Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu não havia percebido... O dois dados são apresentados na linha selecionada. Então se eu selecionar a segunda ou terceira linhas aparecerão os dados "Sim" e "1".

Comment: E se você criar um Campo Calculado no DataSet que alimenta esse Grid?

Comment: Tente adicionar no final do código, depois do `IF`: `dbgPesquisar.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect,Column.Field,State);`

Comment: Andrey. Quando essa linha é adicionada, a exibição das informações são invertidas. Em todas as três linhas aparecem os valores reais (0, 1, 1) e na linha selecionada também aparece "Sim" ou "Não" dependendo do valor (se é 0 ou 1).

Comment: @Júnior Moreira. Não estou utilizando Fields Editor pois é uma tela genérica e os dados são trazidos por meio de uma instrução SQL em um TFDQuery. Então acho que não dá para fazer dessa maneira.

Comment: @Andrey. Quando essa linha é adicionada, a exibição das informações são invertidas. Em todas as três linhas aparecem os valores reais (0, 1, 1) e na linha selecionada também aparece "Sim" ou "Não" dependendo do valor (se é 0 ou 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro então passar para a própria consulta SQL resolver:

algo como:

```
CASE Ativa
 WHEN '0' THEN
 'Não'
 ELSE
 'Sim'
 END Ativa
```

Dessa forma o resultado ja vem pronto para ser exibido.

Comment: Valeu Júnior !!! Problema resolvido. Funcionou direitinho. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não Sei se funciona no Delphi para Android
mais em Desktop utilizo o OnGetText

Exemplo

```
if QryPesquisaclaAtiva.AsString = '0' 
then Text:='Não'
else Text:='Sim';
```

Comment: Oi Paulo. Obrigado pelo retorno. Eu esqueci de mencionar... Esses campos exibidos no DBGrid não são persistentes. Eles são o resultado de uma consulta SQL de um TFDQuery. O seja, eles não foram adicionados ao TFDQuery através do Fields Editor. Então não dá para uitilizar os eventos OnGetText e OnSetText., correto ?

Comment: Oi Paulo. Obrigado pelo retorno. Eu esqueci de mencionar... Esses campos exibidos no DBGrid não são persistentes. Eles são o resultado de uma consulta SQL de um TFDQuery. O seja, eles não foram adicionados ao TFDQuery através do Fields Editor. Então não dá para uitilizar os eventos OnGetText e OnSetText., correto ?

Comment: So para entender um pouco, ele é tipo um campo calculado?.

Comment: É uma tela de consulta genérica. Então os campos que serão retornados no DBGrid serão diferentes, de acordo com a tabela que estou consultando. Ou seja, eu tenho um TFDQuery no qual a instrução SQL se altera sempre. Portanto não posso utilizar o Fields Editor senão os campos ficam persistentes no .DFM e ocasiona erro na aplicação quando alterar o SQL.. Acho que é isso. Abraço.